# How to improve performance of following query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-tuning

The execution  plan is showing 3 warning messages for following query:

```
set statistics io on;
select DISTINCT r.CASE_ID as RequisitionId,
e.BV_Employee_Code as EmployeeCode,e.CASE_ID as CaseID,
e.BV_First_Name as FirstName,e.BV_Last_Name as LastName,
e.BV_Email as Email,e.BV_Status as 'Status', e.BV_hrmsFlag as 'hrmsFlag',
l.BV_Country as 'Country',l.BV_LocationCode,l.BV_LocationName,
DV.BV_Division_Code as Division_Code ,DV.BV_Division_Name, 
AQ.BV_hiringreason,
CASE WHEN BV_Offer_Annual_Rate IS NULL AND BV_OFFER IS NULL AND BV_OFFER_TITLE IS NULL AND BV_Approved_By IS NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ISMANUALHIRED, e.BV_SSN as SSN 
from CW_V_REQN r 
inner join CW_TL_Employee__Requisition er on r.CASE_ID=er.TO_ID 
inner join CW_V_EMPLOYEE e on e.CASE_ID =er.FROM_ID 
inner join CW_TL_Requisition__Location_Master rl on r.CASE_ID=rl.FROM_ID 
inner join CW_V_LOCTMAST l on l.CASE_ID=rl.TO_ID 
inner join CW_V_LOCTMAST l1 ON (l1.CASE_ID = rl.TO_ID) 
inner join CW_TL_LocationMaster__Division_Master ld ON (ld.FROM_ID = rl.TO_ID) 
inner join CW_V_DIVISION dv ON (dv.CASE_ID = ld.TO_ID) 
inner join CW_TL_UserContactInfo__Location_Master ul on l.CASE_ID=ul.TO_ID 
inner join CW_V_USERCONT uc on uc.CASE_ID=ul.FROM_ID 
inner join CW_TL_Employee__Applicant_Requisition_Details ea ON (ea.FROM_ID = er.FROM_ID) 
inner join CW_V_AREQDETA aq ON (aq.CASE_ID = ea.TO_ID)
left join CW_TL_Employee__Employee_Job_Offer ee ON (EE.FROM_ID = er.FROM_ID) 
left join CW_V_EMPJOBOF ej ON (ej.CASE_ID = ee.TO_ID AND ej.BV_REQUISITIONID = r.CASE_ID) 
where e.BV_Status  in('Pending','Employed','LOA','Suspended','Terminated','Pre-Screening') 
and uc.BV_Login_Name='vpawar'
ORDER BY r.CASE_ID ASC
```

Statistics is as follows:

```
(995 row(s) affected)
Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 29, logical reads 442, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'CW_TB_AREQDETA'. Scan count 0, logical reads 6115, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'CW_TL_71'. Scan count 999, logical reads 3002, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'CW_TB_EMPLOYEE'. Scan count 0, logical reads 5205, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'CW_TL_59'. Scan count 1, logical reads 26, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'CW_TB_LOCTMAST'. Scan count 1, logical reads 16791, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'CW_TL_130'. Scan count 1, logical reads 21, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'CW_CT_USERCONT'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'CW_TB_USERCONT'. Scan count 1, logical reads 81, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'CW_TL_30'. Scan count 1, logical reads 44, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'CW_TB_REQN'. Scan count 1, logical reads 40, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'CW_TL_65'. Scan count 1, logical reads 14, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'CW_TB_DIVISION'. Scan count 1, logical reads 6, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'CW_TL_24'. Scan count 1, logical reads 14, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'CW_TB_EMPJOBOF'. Scan count 1, logical reads 145, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Threee sort  operators are telling:

> Operator used tempdb to spill data during execution with spill level 1

I think the select clause is problematic, if  i trim no of columns there those warnings are gone. I have tried to add new indexes or modified existing ones to include covering columns.If my select clause is limited to the table CW_V_EMPLOYEE then these warnings go away &   I get advised to add missing index which I added but without any effect.

**Edit**:
I rewrote the query as follows:

```
set statistics time on; 
set statistics io on;
with LocDivUserCont_CTE as
(
select r.CASE_ID,loc.BV_Country as Country, loc.BV_LocationCode, 
loc.BV_LocationName,
dv.BV_Division_Code as Division_Code,dv.BV_Division_Name
from CW_V_REQN as r
inner join CW_TL_Requisition__Location_Master rl on r.CASE_ID=rl.FROM_ID 
inner join CW_V_LOCTMAST loc on loc.CASE_ID=rl.TO_ID 
inner join CW_TL_LocationMaster__Division_Master ld ON (ld.FROM_ID = 
rl.TO_ID) 
inner join CW_V_DIVISION dv ON (dv.CASE_ID = ld.TO_ID) 
inner join CW_TL_UserContactInfo__Location_Master ul on loc.CASE_ID=ul.TO_ID 
inner join CW_V_USERCONT uc on uc.CASE_ID=ul.FROM_ID 
where  uc.BV_Login_Name='vpawar'
)

select distinct  r.CASE_ID as RequisitionId,
e.BV_Employee_Code as EmployeeCode,e.CASE_ID as CaseID,
e.BV_First_Name as FirstName,e.BV_Last_Name as LastName,
e.BV_Email as Email,e.BV_Status as 'Status', e.BV_hrmsFlag as 'hrmsFlag',e.BV_SSN as SSN,
aq.BV_hiringreason,
CASE WHEN BV_Offer_Annual_Rate IS NULL AND BV_OFFER IS NULL AND BV_OFFER_TITLE IS NULL AND BV_Approved_By IS NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ISMANUALHIRED
from CW_V_REQN r 
inner join CW_TL_Employee__Requisition er on r.CASE_ID = er.TO_ID 
inner join CW_V_EMPLOYEE e on e.CASE_ID = er.FROM_ID 
inner join CW_TL_Employee__Applicant_Requisition_Details ea ON (ea.FROM_ID = er.FROM_ID) 
inner join CW_V_AREQDETA aq ON (aq.CASE_ID = ea.TO_ID)
inner join LocDivUserCont_CTE on r.CASE_ID = LocDivUserCont_CTE.CASE_ID
left join CW_TL_Employee__Employee_Job_Offer ee ON (EE.FROM_ID = er.FROM_ID) 
left join CW_V_EMPJOBOF ej ON (ej.CASE_ID = ee.TO_ID AND ej.BV_REQUISITIONID = r.CASE_ID) 
where e.BV_Status  in('Pending','Employed','LOA','Suspended','Terminated','Pre-Screening') 
order by r.CASE_ID desc;
set statistics io off;
set statistics time off;
```

With this all warnings in "sort" operator are gone.Here is list of scan & logical read data as per earlier query & current query.It is taking less time also. You will see that the logical reads for table CW_TB_LOCTMAST has drastically reduced from 16779 to 15, though for table CW_TB_REQN it has just doubled from 40 to 80.

> Table   |Before Scan  |Before Logical Read |After Scan    |After Logical Read
>   Workfile| 0   |0  |0  |0
>   Worktable |29 |442    |0  |0
>   CW_TB_AREQDETA    |0  |6115   |0  |6115
>   CW_TL_71  |999    |3002   |1  |15
>   CW_TB_EMPLOYEE    |0  |5205   |0  |5205
>   CW_TL_59  |4060   |8668   |1  |15
>   CW_TB_LOCTMAST    |1  |16779  |1  |15
>   CW_TL_130 |1  |21 |1  |21
>   CW_CT_USERCONT    |1  |2  |1  |2
>   CW_TB_USERCONT    |1  |81 |1  |81
>   CW_TL_30  |1  |44 |1  |44
>   CW_TB_REQN    |1  |40 |2  |80
>   CW_TL_65  |1  |14 |1  |14
>   CW_TB_DIVISION    |1  |6  |1  |2
>   CW_TL_24  |1  |14 |1  |14
>   CW_TB_EMPJOBOF    |1  |145    |1  |145

However, should I go with this 2nd query, am I missing something?

Comment: Spills are often due to low memory estimates. Try updating stats (and perhaps creating stats) the tables. Be aware that nested views may be problematic for optimization.

Comment: Use the Display Execution Plan on SQL Server Management Studio to identify what join generates the problem (look for the node that needs more time to calculate).

Comment: Those aliases make no sense in that query. "a" for `CW_V_REQN` (there's not a single `a` in there), "d" for `CW_TL_Employee__Requisition` (not a `d` in there either) and "i" for `CW_V_USERCONT`?. I recommend having a read here: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3) You'll find using good (and just as importantly consistent) aliasing will make your queries far easier for everyone, including yourself, to read.

Comment: @Larnu, followed your suggestion, rewrote the query, I have also updated stats for tables which were showing warning in "sort" operator.

Comment: Even after updating stats, problem persists, it is estimating no of rows to lower than actual which is creating problem.

Comment: Suppose in one index some column is in ascending order, but my query needs it in descending order, will my query be able to use the index? I guess it will be able to do so.

Comment: I rebuilt indexes in some of the tables, I expected fragmentation %age to get reduced to zero, it remains unaffected. I updated statistics as per @Dan Guzman's suggestion, but it still estimating wrong, and if we modify the select clause to get columns only from 1 or 2 tables, then there is no warning.